# Unreal Engine 5 support HTML5?

Tags: unreal-engine5

Please explain if I understand correctly that Unreal Engine 5 no longer supports the HTML5 Web platform?

I found on this page: https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/HTML5/

Following text:

> As of Unreal Engine 4.24, support for the HTML5 platform has been
> migrated out of the engine to a public Platform Extension that can be
> maintained and improved by community members. Documentation for the
> HTML5 Platform Extension is hosted alongside the GitHub repository.

So Epic Games no longer officially supports the Web platform?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is correct. As of Unreal Engine 4.24, Epic Games has officially migrated support for the HTML5 platform out of the engine. It has been transformed into a public Platform Extension that can now be maintained and improved by community members.

This means that Epic Games no longer provides official support for the HTML5 platform within Unreal Engine. Instead, the responsibility for maintaining and improving HTML5 support lies with the community. The documentation for the HTML5 Platform Extension is hosted alongside the GitHub repository, allowing community members to contribute to its development.

It's worth noting that this change indicates a shift in Epic Games' focus and allocation of resources. By transitioning the HTML5 platform to community maintenance, Epic Games can concentrate its efforts on other areas while still enabling community collaboration and support for HTML5 in Unreal Engine.

Comment: Thank you, it's a pity, judging by the date of the last update on the github - the HTML5 community project for the Unreal Engine is dead.

Comment: At least two of your answers appear likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: In this case, I received a very similar answer when pasting the question into ChatGPT, including the phrase, for example, *"The documentation for the HTML5 Platform Extension is hosted alongside the GitHub repository, indicating that it is now a community-driven effort rather than being officially supported by Epic Games."*

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.